# API only controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm working on API only application with Rails5.
However I have a good reason to have couple of view for the web.

I do have a api/v1/controller/password_reset_controller to create the request and send the email to user

I also have a controller/password_reset_controller with new, edit, create, update and the respective web views.

Everything is working fine right now but I'm felling it is not DRY.

Is there a way/need to combine both controllers and still have it as an endpoint and web resource?

routes.rb

```
  ...
  resources :password_resets, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  scope module: "api" do
    namespace :v1 do
     # Reset Pass
     resources :password_resets, only: [:create]
  ...
```

EDIT: Weird wording

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could tell the route to use the Api::V1::PasswordResetsController like this:

```
resources :password_resets, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update], controller: 'api/v1/password_resets'
```

Then you could get rid of the other controller entirely.